# Mod rewrite rule for mapping one or two parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This rules allow to enter urls like:

```
example.com/my-account-dashboard  
example.com/my-account-dashboard/1
```

which are pretty urls for:

```
example.com?page=my-account-dashboard  
example.com?page=my-account-dashboard&id=1
```

This works fine so far. But internaly the links are with those parameters. Is it possible to redirect (or something) to the pretty urls if possible? **What are the rewrite rules for that?**

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The question is: how are the rewrite rule to redirect urls in the format example.com?page=my-account-dashboard&id=1 to example.com/my-account-dashboard/1. Basically how to use the structure example.com/parameter-page/parameter-id/?additional-parameters

Comment: did you mean example.com/my-account-dashboard/2?name=someone to example.com/?page=my-account-dashboard&id=2&name=someone ?

Comment: exactly ;) The rules i have mentioned above works if you enter the url in the correct (prettyfied) way but not if you do it with the parameters (native). I need a rule that forces the "pretty" format because the links have all the native format with regular php parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a few remarks about your current code which contains some errors.

1) `RewriteCond` only applies on the very next `RewriteRule`. So your second `RewriteRule` can match without that condition (you can try it, you'll see). You need to put (again) that condition to the other `RewriteRule` (or use `S` skip flag to simulate if/else condition but it gets complicated for nothing).

2) I'm pretty sure you don't want to use `QSA` flag the way you do. By using it, you tell `mod_rewrite` to append any query string to the rewrite. Example: `example.com/my-account-dashboard/?foo=bar` will rewrite to `/?page=my-account-dashboard&foo=bar`. So unless you really want that, you don't need it. A lot of people think that they need `QSA` when adding some query string directly in the rewrite, just like you do. Again, this is not an error that will make everything crash, but still it's not totally correct.

3) Your rules create **duplicate content** which is bad for SEO (referencing). For instance, `example.com/my-account-dashboard` and `example.com/my-account-dashboard/` (notice the trailing slash) both lead to the same page. But search engines won't consider them as the same. I invite you to search "duplicate content" on Google (or any other search engine you like) and have a look at it. A simple way to avoid this is to chose either with or without the trailing slash.

Now that the base is clear, let's answer to your question. You can't simply use a redirect `R` from old-url to new-url because you'd end up with an infinite loop. Something is there for this problem: `THE_REQUEST`. When `mod_rewrite` uses it, it is able to know that it comes from a direct client request, not a redirect/rewrite by itself.

All-in-one, here is how your code should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect old-url /?page=XXX to new-url equivalent /XXX
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/\?page=([^/&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# Redirect old-url /?page=XXX&id=YYY to new-url equivalent /XXX/YYY
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/\?page=([^/&\s]+)&id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# if /XXX is not a file/directory then rewrite to /?page=XXX
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /?page=$1 [L]

# if /XXX/YYY is not a file/directory then rewrite to /?page=XXX&id=YYY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

NB: i chose to use the "without trailing slash" option (e.g. `example.com/my-account-dashboard` and `example.com/my-account-dashboard/1`). Feel free to ask if you want with.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your detailed answer. This is looking pretty good so far. QSA is needed because there are some additional parameters sometimes like ./?page=search&search=asdf. How is that done? Also it seems like there are problems with php redirects and forms ... probably that is caused by additional parameters

Comment: Well, feel free to keep using `QSA` flag if you need it. I mean, maybe i wasn't clear enough on this. If `search=asdf` is something **from** the original url (before rewriting), then you need `QSA` in order to tell `mod_rewrite` to append `search=asdf` to your rewrite page, e.g. `/?page=search&search=asdf`. Otherwise, you don't need it. For the forms issue, could you tell me what the `action` value is for each ? You should not rely on the fact that old-url are being redirected to new-url, otherwise you get such issue with forms. Please replace old-url by new-url format everywhere in your pages